# On the fly LESS compiler for java web app?

Tags: java, css, jakarta-ee, servlets, less

I am looking for a way to compile CSS LESS files on the server side on demand during development. For example if the browser makes a request to /assets/css/foo.css I want the server to notice that there is an /assets/css/foo.less file and then to have this file complied and the resulting css returned. I am guessing there must be a LESS servlet somewhere that can do this?

I am running tomcat 7 with Spring MVC application

How do I configure a Java Web App to do on the fly LESS compilation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [Servlet Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).  I **was** not aware of an off the shelf one that does LESS compiling and would have started to make one using [lesscss-java](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java), but now I can see there is a larger project called [Web Resource Optimizer for Java - wro4j](http://wro4j.github.io/wro4j/) with server side [LESS support](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/LessCssSupport).

Comment: Just a hint regarding on the fly less compilation using wro4j: http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/AbstractProcessorsFilter

Comment: @AlexObjelean What to do if you want the filter in development process only?

Comment: The WroFilter has a flag for enabling/disabling. You can set it in development only and everything should work with no other change.

Answer (score 7):

It would be **simpler** (and more effective) to first compile your less files to css files, during the build of your webapp.
As an example, when using **Maven**, we use the [lesscss-maven-plugin](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin) (*compile* goal, *process-sources* phase) to generate css files from less files. Then only the *css* files are used and packaged in the webapp. No *less* files are used dynamically.
Another advantage is that less files are compiled before the webapp is deployed, so compilation errors are detected sooner.

Configuration example in pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/less</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/css</outputDirectory>
        <compress>true</compress>
        <includes>
            <include>main.less</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I agree this is good before going into production by when a designer is just fiddling around with settings run maven every time you change a small thing kills productivity

Answer (score 5):

What we do is we have two modes : dev and production.

For dev, use the official less css js compiler, which compiles on the fly:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="${...}/style.less" />
<script>(window.less = window.less || {}).env = 'development';</script>
<script src="${staticContext}/lib/less-1.3.3.js"></script>
```

in your HTML

for prod, use the compiled styles by https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${staticContext}/css/style.css" />
```