# Is there a tomcat module that dynamically compiles SASS or LESS into CSS?

Tags: css, tomcat, sass, less

We are thinking about switching our project from plain CSS to LESS or SASS. As we use tomcat, it would be quite helpful to have the SASS/LESS compiled dynamically to CSS and server to the client as CSS, similar as http://modsass.sourceforge.net/

After googling a while, I think there is no such module yet - or did I miss something?

Client-side LESS-compiling might be a bit slow (especially on mobile devices).
The fallback solution would be to statically compile the files, but a dynamic solution I would expect that development is eased a bit.

I'm happy to hear your suggestions!

Comment: You probably have a build chain (ant, maven, etc.) to build the production version of your application from your source code. You can simply plug a call to nodejs from this build chain.

Comment: Yes, we do use ant. What are your experiences during development? There, we normally don't have to use any ant etc. which speeds things up a bit.

Comment: I have a shell script I use to build the css files, and I call this script from ant where I already do a bunch of things to build my application.  When you already work with heavy and slow beasts like tomcat and eclipse, compiling .less files doesn't look like a slow operation.

Comment: By the way: From what I read so far, LESS and SASS seems to be quite similar in terms of functionality and available tools. I'm also happy about any suggestion what to consider when making this choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On the fly LESS compiler for java web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868734/on-the-fly-less-compiler-for-java-web-app)

Comment: Thank for this hint. In fact, we found a solution ... I should check which one we are using.